# concat two columns as one within group concat

Tags: mysql

If i have a query as follows:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
group_CONCAT('IF(`mailer_id` = ', `mailer_id`, ',edition,NULL) AS mailer_id',`mailer_id`))
 INTO @sql FROM crm_support_inquiry;
```

Suppose i want to group concatenate mailer_id as the concatenation of two columns along with seperator how that can be done.
In place of "edition" i want two columns to be concatenated as one column. The two columns are 'edition' as well as 'sent_on'.
Right now in my code i have entered only edition column.Suggest the changes

Comment: Are you sure you want `GROUP_CONCAT()`? Your query doesn't have a `GROUP BY` clause. Maybe you want `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()`?

Comment: Neither is it clear what you want, nor do I see an edition or sent_on column in your code. Add sample data and desired result.

Comment: Try to improve the readability of question. It will help you to get quick and correct ans. :)